# Java - Quirk with reading lines from a Path

Tags: java, nio

I seem to be having a randomly occurring issue that I hope someone can shed light on.  I am reading in a file and outputting the contents.  I have one test file, which can be read in 90% of the time. However, once in a while it incorrectly reports that the test file has 0 lines.  Is there a reason this is happening?  I would expect that it always reads in the contents. A bare bones example is shown below:

```
public void foo (Path path){
    System.out.println("Exists?"+ Files.exists(path)); // Always says true
    List<String>lines = Files.readAllLines(path);
    System.out.println("NumLines:"+ lines.size()); // Sometimes 0, sometimes 7
}
```

I have also tried this with a BufferedReader(new FileReader(path.ToFile())) and get the same results

Comment: Where is the file located? A local drive or a network share?

Comment: It's on my local drive. And it's a 5kb file, so not much in it

Comment: Could you disable any anti-virus and try to reproduce?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't believe it has anything to do with that.

Comment: Is this OpenJDK or Oracle? Might need to file a bug for it or update your JDK/JRE Since it's IO related it could even be related to the disk controller driver. There really are a lot of factors involved.

Comment: similar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22652809/system-io-file-readalllines-returns-zero-strings Is this a file that you create prior to running this method? If so then you'd need to make sure you flush any write operations as that will definitely be non-deterministic. Any details like that would be helpful, as this stands there is not enough information.

Comment: this code should not compile - unhandled IOException  - and that could make a difference.

Comment: I've got Oracle v1.8.0_66 .  The code was just a quick hand-written example... you can throw an IOException to the method if you need it to compile

Comment: When you get zero, try opening the file in some other tool, like a text editor.  Also try adding code that prints the file’s overall size, such as `System.out.println(Files.size(path));`.

Comment: And since my last comment I can't replicate it anymore (even though it's been happening for a few days). Law of irony...